# Problem in Kotlin with inserting Int array elements into String list using For loop (toString is used)

Tags: arrays, string, list, kotlin

Kotlin problem:

> 1. Create an integer array of numbers called **numbers**, from 11 to 15.
> 2. Create an empty mutable list for Strings.
> 3. Write a **for** loop that loops over the array and adds the string
>    representation of each number to the list.

I have tried the following:

```
import java.util.*
var numbers = intArrayOf(11,12,13,14,15)
var myList = mutableListOf<String>()
for (element in numbers) {
    myList.add(Arrays.toString(element))
}
```

But it gives me an error:

```
error: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun toString(p0: Array<(out) Any!>!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: BooleanArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: ByteArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: CharArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: DoubleArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: FloatArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: IntArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: LongArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
public open fun toString(p0: ShortArray!): String! defined in java.util.Arrays
    myList.add(Arrays.toString(element))
                      ^
```

Later I solved the problem with

```
myList.add(Arrays.toString(numbers))
```

Why first code didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.toString()` is for converting an entire Array of data into a single String, so it's not the right tool for your task anyway. (If you were going to do this, in Kotlin, it should be preferred to call `joinToString()` on the Array instead of using Java's `Arrays` utility class.)

You want to convert each individual `Int` into a `String` one at a time, so you should use:

```
myList.add(element.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first method doesn't work because `Arrays.toString` takes an *array* and converts it to a string, as you can see from all the overloads listed in the error message. `element` is not an array - it is an element of the `numbers` array, i.e. an `Int`. Therefore your first way doesn't work.

Note that your second way adds the single string `"[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]"`, rather than the 5 strings `"11"`, `"12"`, `"13"`, `"14"`, `"15"` to the list. If you want to add those 5 strings, you should call `toString` on `element`:

```
for (element in numbers) {
    myList.add(element.toString())
}
```

Also, it is not recommended to use the Java `Arrays.toString` method. If you want to produce the string `"[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]"`, use `numbers.contentToString()` instead.